# Is it possible to define a value of a previous definition

Tags: c-preprocessor

I have following

```
#define COMPANY ABC  // should be happen by calling the script via Argument

#ifdef COMPANY
#define COMPANY  // -> now ABC should be defined
#endif

#if defined (ABC)
  // ...
#elif defined (DEF)
  // ...
#else
  // ...
#endif
```

---

My idea was:

1. `COMPANY` is defined, value is "ABC"
2. `#ifdef COMPANY` becomes true, so the next define will be executed
3. `#define COMPANY` will be replaced by `#define ABC` because of the definition of `COMPANY` itself

OK, it doesn't work because the preprocessor doesn't replace its own definitions...

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to do this?

No, it is not possible to do dynamically in a ny way. The token after `#define` is taken literally and is not subject to expansions. It is not possible to define a macro based on computation of other macro.

Typically, enumerations and choices are done as following:

```
#define COMPANY ABC  // should be happen by calling the script via Argument

#define ABC 1
#define DEF 2

#if COMPANY == ABC
// for company ABC
#elif COMPANY == DEF
// for company DEF
#else
#error COMPANY has to be ABC or DEF
#endif
```